# Twitter-Typeahead autocompletion is not working?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-typeahead

What is wrong with this code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            var customers = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                remote: {
                    url: '/api/customers?query=%QUERY',
                    wildcard: '%QUERY'
                }
            });

            $('#customer').typeahead(null, {
                name: 'customers',
                display: 'name',
                source: customers
            });
        });
</script>
```

When i type text into a textbox. The Ajax call is issue to /api/customer/query="something" but the  autocompletion is not working.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**How to fix it ?**
Thanks

Comment: What data are you returning from the `/api/customers` call? It's that logic which you need to debug

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  /api/customers give me data back...i checked it in Response Tab in Google Chrome.

Comment: @could you post a portion of returned data here !

Comment: @BooBerr'ita I posted picture inside a question....

Comment: WHICH VERSION OT TWITTER TYOE AHEAD YOU'RE USING ?

Comment: @BooBerr'ita : Version: 0.11.1

Comment: that's wierd should work properly ?

Comment: yes it's wierd? @BooBerr'ita